# Considering $l^\infty(X)$ as a C* algebra, how to show that the maximal ideal is $S(X) = \beta X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, c-star-algebras

I have read in a few sources that 'it is clear to see that' or 'it is well known that' the maximal ideal of $l^\infty (X)$ is $\beta X$ (i,e,e the space of all ultrafilters on X). But I cannot see why!

Comment: There's a good chance that $l^\infty(X)$ is intended to be defined with respect to counting measure on $X$ and that "the maximal ideal" is intended to mean "the space of maximal ideals". Then the statement is correct. The ideal corresponding to an ultrafilter $U$ on $X$ is the set of those $f\in l^\infty(X)$ that converge to $0$ with respect to $U$. Check that this is an ideal (easy), it's a maximal ideal (because the quotient is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb R$), that distinct ultrafilters give distinct ideals (easy), and that all maximal ideals arise this way (work needed here).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Dear Andreas. Thank you very much for your reply. I did indeed miss out those essential assumptions. I was wondering if you have any recommendations for links about this- especially showing steps for the part that all maximal ideals arise like this.

Comment: Correction to previous comment: The quotient is isomorphic to the ultrapower of $\mathbb R$ with respect to $U$, not to $\mathbb R$. (I need to wake up.)  Fortunately, that's still a field, so maximality still follows.

Comment: I conjecture that this is in the book "Rings of Continuous Functions" by Gillman and Jerison. Unfortunately, I can't verify the conjecture because my copy of the book is in my office, which is off-limits because of the coronavirus.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much! I have found a preview of a relevant chapter of the book on springerlink and it promises to prove exactly this! I just wonder why I have seen a few papers say 'it is clear to see that...' when the proof doesn't seem to be trivial at all!

Comment: Too busy to right up an answer right now, but one way to see this is to note that $\ell^\infty(X)$ is the multiplier algebra of $C_0(X)$ (giving $X$ the discrete topology), and for any locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, the multiplier algebra of $C_0(X)$ is $C(\beta X)$.  I believe proofs of these claims can be found in the first few chapters of Wegge-Olsen's book on $K$-theory for $C^*$-algebras